# FtpWebRequest ListDirectory truncated at 10,000 files

Tags: .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftpwebresponse

I am trying to get an FTP directory listing. I have more than 10,000 files in my folder and it seems that the list I get back is truncated at 10,000 files. Is there anything I can do so that I can get all the files back?

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://mysite.com");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

request.Credentials = myCache;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
string Datastring = reader.ReadToEnd();

string[] myfiles = Datastring.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: yeah it's similar the difference I suppose is that he's using software whereas I am writing my own code. It's no use to me if a bit of software can do it because I need to do it from .net code.

Comment: Point is that it's a common limitation and appears to be a server setting.